# onchange of FilteringSelect do not work

Tags: javascript, dojo

Same code I'm using of dojo [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html)
just downloaded code work fine but onchange event do not fire on my project.
I have make it to work by firing onblur `onBlur: function(){alert(3)}`
What thing may cause onchange  event not fire?

```
var filteringSelect = new FilteringSelect({
        id: "stateSelect",
        name: "state",
        value: "CA",
        store: stateStore,
        searchAttr: "name",     
        onChange: function(){alert(3)}
    }, "stateSelect");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put different id on the array like:

```
var stateStore = new Memory({
        data: [
            {name:"Alabama", id:"AL"},
            {name:"Alaska", id:"AK"}
              ]
});
```

1. If there is no id on your Array, onChange event will not fire
2. If the value of two id are same, onChange event will fire just for the first time.

Comment: That's indeed the purpose of an ID ;) If you have no ID it cannot change successfully since it will throw an error. If you have a double ID, it will throw an error if you change your value. If you provided the ID from the start, it would have been easier to help ;) But still, nice find.

Answer (score 1):

I think something else is wrong since it's working fine here. I even made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhqVL/) to show it's working.

Also, there is another way (I think it's more preferred too) by using the `dojo/on` module:

```
on(filteringSelect, 'change', function() {
       alert(3); 
});
```

Another JSFiddle to demonstrate this can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fhqVL/1/).

Comment: Then I think there is another problem since you can see that both examples ar working fine. What version of Dojo are you using? Can you post a more complete example?

Comment: I found the error. I should include `id` on the array otherwise onchange event will not fire.  But the problem I am facing now is that the onChange event will fire just for the first time. To fire onChange event after then I've to press something by the keyboard.

Comment: Then you should look for more differences between the example of Dojo and your code. You can see in both my examples (and on Dojo) that they work fine. The `id` is indeed necessary since it's used in a similar way like `<option value="AK">Alaska</option>`. You always have a value that's displayed, and a unique value that's used as identifier.

Comment: dojo/on should only be used for events on dom nodes. Widgets already have their own "on" method. You can either set the onChange function directly as vusan did, or call filteringSelect.on("change", callback)